# How to read testbot feedback / get more info

Tags: 8, testing, version-control

I have created a [patch for migrate_spreadsheet](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_spreadsheet/issues/2932815), unfortunately it will not pass the testbot. Instead that gives me this (to me cryptic / uninformative) message:

> fail: [run-tests.sh check] Line 0 of : FATAL
>   Drupal\Tests\migrate_spreadsheet\Unit\SpreadsheetIteratorTest: test
>   runner returned a non-zero error code (255).

Where/what is line 0? My first change compared to the original file was on line 7, where I corrected a class name. The only other two changes in that file where in the docs.

So what does this fail mean? 
How can I get more info from the testbot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

If you click the colored patch result (above), you will get to a [detailed page](https://www.drupal.org/pift-ci-job/847728). On the top of that page there is a link 'View results on dispatcher'. That will get you to the test. Then go to the 'Console output' (on the left) ([direct link](https://dispatcher.drupalci.org/job/drupal8_contrib_patches/19094/console)).

The actual error appears to be:

> 13:56:12 PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet' not found in
>   /var/www/html/modules/contrib/migrate_spreadsheet/tests/src/Unit/SpreadsheetIteratorTest.php
>   on line 187

Comment: Not sure what you mean with *the colored patch result*, I think you mean the 'View results' link? The rest of your answer is very helpful though. Thanks, silly I missed that link :-) So it's view results -> view results on displatcher -> console log and then look for the colored text.

Comment: I was referring to the background of the test. A screenshot is now included :-) Good luck fixing the patch!

Comment: Proper feedback really helps, thanks again for pointing it out to me. The patch is ok now and already committed even. Partly thanks to you! :-)